# How to swipe the layout(linear/relative..) in android

Tags: java, android

How to swipe the linear layout left or right side.In that linear layout i have one delete button by default that is in invisible and also some other widgets which all are visible state, When swipe left side the linear layout i need to make it visible that delete button and when swipe right than i need invisible that delete button.

Comment: Do you mean viewpager

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a   `swipeLayout`.

https://github.com/lzyzsd/SwipeLayout

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?
In case I understand you correctly have a look at this library [SwipeListView](https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView)

[image]